# Parse error: syntax error in PHP?

Tags: php, web, ftp

Hi guys I'm following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/connecting-to-an-external-database-with-nusoap--mobile-15832) tutorial and I'm getting an extremely strange error message in my PHP when I try and run it in the web browser. The code is as follows:

```
    <?php
// Pull in the NuSOAP
require_once('nusoap.php');
// Create the server instance
$server = new soap_server();
// Initialize WSDL support
//(MyService is name of our service)
$server----->configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');
        // Character encoding
        $server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
        //-------------------------------------------------
        //Registrations of our functions
        //-------------------------------------------------
        //Our web service functions will be here.
        //-------------------------------------------------
        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
        $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

Which is exactly as it's written in the tutorial, yet I keep getting this error message every time I run the PHP file:

UPDATE now I'm getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DEC in
>   /home/a1335235/public_html/MyService.php on line 8

Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: `code require_once('nusoap.php');` should be `require_once('nusoap.php');`

Comment: Hey mark cheers buddy that seemed to have taken that error message away, I'm getting a new error message and I've updated the code in my original post to represent that.

Comment: `$server----->configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');` should be `$server->configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');`

Comment: @logikurl: Stackoverflow does not work well with that. You're changing the meaning of the question. The original question should/could be closed as typo IMHO. Next to that, consult the error reference before asking for specific error messages.

Comment: someone forgot its finger on the dash

Comment: And as you've got a problem with code from a tutorial: Contact their support, they should learn about which errors got users with their code.

Comment: I really think you should find a better tutorial, one that isn't riddled with errors

Comment: @hakre apologies I just figured it would make sense updating the post as opposed to making a completely new one, noted for next time however

Comment: @RoyalBg finger on the dash?

Comment: @Jimbo - not necessary.... I work on the principle that if my answer would fit within the 140 characters of a tweet, then I simply post it as a comment; and I've never downvoted anybody for using that as an answer.... especially where they add extra commentary on the problem

Comment: @hakre You're right, I've left a message for the original author of the tutorial

Comment: @MarkBaker trying to mate that was one of my last hopes for calling data from a DB on windows phone, and that turns out to be filled with errors, how convenient! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark Baker said in the comments (and I'll delete this if he posts first), your code is:

```
code require_once();
```

First and foremost `code` is not PHP. This should be `require_once` and you can see this in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). Secondly, `require_once` is a *language construct*. It's not a function call, so you don't need the `()`. You should have:

```
require_once 'nusoap.php';
```

The syntax error is telling you exactly what line the problem is on, so read it and google that bit of code to see how others are doing it and where you are going wrong in the future.

Now your issue is on line 8:

```
$server----->configureWSDL
```

This is not valid PHP either, unless you've heavily modifed the source code of the language, which you haven't. Change this to:

```
$server->configureWSDL()
```

That's how you call methods on objects. You should be reading the manual on [Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) to see how this works.

Comment: Hey Jimbo thanks for the tip, isn't the 'MyService' already within the brackets as you stated? configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');

Comment: Yep - they're called parameters and can be variable, I'm just showing you how to call a method.

Comment: But the code that's already there, is that not valid PHP then?

Comment: No, you have `$server----->configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');`. You should have `$server->configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');`. *Note: There's no massive arrow, just one `->`*.

Comment: Top lad Jimbo, I was checking out the PHP list tokens and had changed it to "-->" accordingly, didn't realise an extra dash could do so much damage, cheers man my PHP script is working now.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that php has its own native extension for soap, there is really no need to use nusoap. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php